# Firebase : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 (Configure Multiple project)

Tags: c++, firebase, c++11, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to compile main.ccp to configure my c++ project manually and have it connect to my own firebase.

```
#include "main.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "firebase/app.h"
#include "firebase/database.h"
int main()
{
    firebase::AppOptions secondary_app_options;
    secondary_app_options.set_api_key("API_KEY");
    secondary_app_options.set_app_id("APP_ID");
    secondary_app_options.set_project_id("PROJ_ID");
    firebase::App* secondary_app = firebase::App::Create(secondary_app_options, "Secondary");
    firebase::database::Database* secondary_database = firebase::database::Database::GetInstance(secondary_app);
    return 0;
}
```

I use the command line to compile : `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.o`
And it output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "firebase::App::Create(firebase::AppOptions const&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in main-9988c0.o
  "firebase::database::Database::GetInstance(firebase::App*, firebase::InitResult*)", referenced from:
      _main in main-9988c0.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I did correctly download and locate all of the framework and library for firebase already. Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: You need to link to the firebase libraries.  `-lfirebase_app -lfirebase_database`.  These libraries are in the lib folder of the SDK : `firebase_cpp_sdk/libs/{PLATFORM}/x86_64`

Comment: I do not know how to link to those libraries on command line. Can you teach me how?